# QED on side of aligned equation

Tags: theorems

How can I put the QED sign of an `aligned` equation inside a proof on the right, rather than in a new line?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} %in the following MWE
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        Here's an equation:
        \begin{equation}
            \begin{aligned}
                \mbox{minimize}\enspace &f(x),\\
                \text{subject to} \enspace & Ax \geq a,\\
                & Bx \geq b,\\
                & Cx \geq c.
            \end{aligned}
        \end{equation}
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Wanted result:
[image]

Comment: Do You want to put QED instead of Your number of equation or just right from the formula?

Comment: I've updated the question to show the desired result.

Comment: added new example

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}

\begin{document}


\begin{proof}
Proof includes a long, multi-line equation.
\begin{align}
Here's an equation:
\mbox{minimize}\enspace &f(x),\nonumber\\
\text{subject to} \enspace & Ax \geq a,\\
& Bx \geq b,\nonumber\\
& Cx \geq c.\qedhere
\end{align}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This approach might work, but only if there's an odd number of lines, otherwise the equation number is not vertically centered

Comment: I think there's four lines in this equation.  The other answer's approach with `aligned` does suffer that problem, however.

Answer (score 0):

This will put the `tombstone` at the end of the last line.

[image: Ax]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} %in the following MWE
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcommand{\QED}{ \par \vspace{-1.7\baselineskip}\qedhere}%  added <<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        Here's an equation:
        \begin{equation}
            \begin{aligned}
                \mbox{minimize}\enspace &f(x),\\
                \text{subject to} \enspace & Ax \geq a,\\
                & Bx \geq b,\\ 
            & Cx \geq c.
            \end{aligned} 
         \end{equation}
     \QED % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to *not* end a proof with a display.

Here's how you can do it: you need to insert negative space in the right amount to cancel the new line and the skip below the display.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} %in the following MWE
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Here's an equation:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
  \mbox{minimize}\enspace &f(x),\\
  \text{subject to} \enspace & Ax \geq a,\\
  & Bx \geq b,\\
  & Cx \geq c.
  \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}                 
\vadjust pre {\nobreak\vskip-\glueexpr\baselineskip+\belowdisplayskip}
\end{proof}

Some text follows
\end{document}
```

[image]